# rubaxa:sortable (Meteor) dying with error "TypeError: templateInstance.collection.findOne is not a function"

Tags: mongodb, meteor, rubaxa-sortable

Using Meteor I implemented a pretty basic rubaxa:sortable instance. Not using multiple sortable lists or anything fancy. Pre-loaded "order" data in my Mongo Collection with unique numbers 1, 2, 3, etc.

Everything displays fine, and lets you sort *once* then the package dies when it tries to save the new order to the DB.

Error in the browser console is:

```
TypeError: templateInstance.collection.findOne is not a function. (In 'templateInstance.collection.findOne(itemId)', 'templateInstance.collection.findOne' is undefined)
adjustOrdersrubaxa_sortable.js:1404
sortableUpdaterubaxa_sortable.js:1446
_dispatchEventrubaxa_sortable.js:1102
_onDroprubaxa_sortable.js:799
(anonymous function)
handleEventrubaxa_sortable.js:853
```

Relevant code snippets below...

Server:

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
Sortable.collections = ['products'];`
```

Client JS:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Mongo.Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
});
```

Client HTML:

```
<div class="sortable target" id="object">
  {{#sortable items=products animation="100" handle=".sortable-handle" ghostClass="sortable-ghost" sortField="order"}}
    {{> productSettingsRow}}
  {{/sortable}}
</div>`

<template name="productSettingsRow">
  <div data-id="{{order}}" class="sortable-item well well-sm">
    <div class="row">
    ...
    <div class="col s5">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input id="{{sku}}-displayName" type="text" value="{{displayName}}">
      </div>
    </div>
     ...
    <div class="col s1">
      <i class="sortable-handle mdi-action-view-headline pull-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried searching on the error; don't see anything quite like this though #578 here seems similar(?):
https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/578

Any suggestions, or any other info I can provide to help debug? (Also posted this to the GitHub repo as suggested.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define collections both on the client and the server. So all you might be missing is to put:

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
Sortable.collections = ['products'];
```

in a shared place, such as `/lib/common.js`.

Comment: Thanks Christian -- good thought. That wasn't it though... I'm already defining the products collection on the client (sorry I didn't include that in my snippet).

I'm not currently specifying Sortable.collections = ['products']; on the client; from the docs it doesn't seem necessary; I tried it just now, just to be sure, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Solution Found...**

The helper that was passing in the "products" collection was set up like this:

```
Template.productSettings.helpers({
  products : function() {
    return Mongo.Products.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

It should have been:

```
Template.productSettings.helpers({
  products : function() {
    return Mongo.Products.find();
  }
});
```

This way it's a pointer rather than an array. rubaxa:sortable doesn't yet handle arrays.

(Still working through a DB storage problem; this plugin doesn't seem to work out of the box with Meteor -- gives "Access Denied" when you try to update. Will try to sort that out tomorrow.)